# Get unpaginated results from Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have pagination enabled by default, which is based on `PageNumberPagination`; this had sufficed until now as the API was only used by a front-end. Now we try to build automation on top of it, and I’d like to pass the full, unpaginated result set back to the client.

Is there a way to disable pagination for specific requests, e.g. if a request parameter is passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did go with a custom pagination class:

```
class Unpaginatable(PageNumberPagination):
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        if getattr(request, 'get_all', False):
            return None

        return super(BuildListPagination, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view=view)
```

Now I just have to set `request.get_all = True` in my viewset and I get all the items.

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: This is basically the same solution you came up with, in a bit fewer lines. I canʼt really elaborate deeper than this as i donʼt work with Django anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I used a similer appraoch to accepted answer

```
class Unpaginatable(PageNumberPagination):
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        if request.query_params.get('get_all', False) == 'true':
            return None

        return super(BuildListPagination, self).paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view=view)
```

now if you pass `?get_all=true` while making the request, you will get unpaginated response.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using page number pagination style, the below solution may be better.

```
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
    if 'page' not in request.query_params:
        return None

    return super().paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)
```

So you simply send a request without the page query_param.

Answer (score 1):

thnaks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62609904/17881270),
Else, if you use limit/offset you can use this in Generic List API View class:

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
    if 'limit' not in self.request.query_params:
        return None
    return super().paginate_queryset(queryset)
```

It worked with python 3.9/ Django 4.0, In my case, this method had no argument named request and view, so I fixed it.

this will also won't render paginator json, when the response is not paginated.

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate this with a request limit set to an unfeasibly large number, but you need to configure Django first:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination'
}
```

Then make a ridiculously high limit request:

`GET https://api.example.org/accounts/?limit=999999999999`

[LimitOffsetPagination
 - django-rest-framework.org](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#limitoffsetpagination)

Answer (score 0):

Actually DRF docs for this is very unclear, and there is no clear answer address this issue. After reading the source code, the followling code works for me.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination


class Unpaginated(LimitOffsetPagination):
    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        self.count = self.get_count(queryset)
        self.limit = self.get_limit(request)
        self.offset = self.get_offset(request)
        self.request = request
        self.display_page_controls = False

        return list(queryset)


class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all().order_by("-id")
    pagination_class = Unpaginated
```

The key here is to override the `paginate_queryset` function in base class and return the whole queryset.

However, overriding this function is not documented at all in the docs or I just missed it.

1. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/
2. https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in the following way:

- make your own pagination class and inherit it from PageNumberPagination
- redefine or add your code (with super()) in get_page_size function.

For me works this case:

def get_page_size(self, request):
super().get_page_size(request)
.......
self.page_size = self.max_page_size
return self.page_size